# Looking for a short story about a robot that didn't want to die alone so he built another robot to keep him company until his "death"?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

I remember reading this short story somewhere. I can't remember all the details very clearly but I do remember it being kind of side and philosophical about life and it becomes a cycle. The story went something like this...:

A robot portraying a human is slowly coming to the end of its life. Not wanting to die alone, he builds another robot and teaches the robot about life and being alive. As time passes the creator robot gets sicker and sicker and the one he creates becomes attached to him.

When it comes time for the creator robot to "die" he instructs the one he created to follow a procedure and to continue living. After the creator dies the surviving robot realizes the creator was a robot. And that with time he would also "die" and would go on to create a robot to do what he did for his creator. And so it becomes a sad cycle.

I can't remember the story very clearly but it was something along the lines of what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

A short story by Japanese author Otsuichi, the story is called '*Song of the Sunny Spot*'. In this story an artificial person is created to keep company with and eventually bury someone who seems to be the last person on earth until his death.

A summary of the story can be found in the fourth paragraph on the following link: https://www.genjipress.com/2009/09/zoo-otsuichi.html

> My favorite story of the batch, “Song of the Sunny Spot”, has the simplicity of a fairy tale and some of the same insight-through-the-fantastic as Stanisław Lem’s best work. The last man on earth has created a robot to bury him when he dies, but there is a great deal more going on besides that, and in the end the robot learns that to be fully human means to contain contradiction, to have both love and hate for the same things at once. It’s beautiful and elegiac, the kind of story I could see being adapted into an animated production by the likes of Makoto (5 cm/sec) Shinkai.

Comment: Can you include some details to show why?

Comment: I've added some details above as well as a link. I also found the PDF of the story from my time in university